# Not giving value when I use inside for loop {{product.i.product_name}} but works fine when {{product.0.product_name}}

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Here is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
product_id = models.AutoField
product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
description = models.CharField(max_length=600)
pub_date = models.DateField()
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="home/images")
```

the *views.py*:

```
def home(request):
products = Product.objects.all()
n = len(products)
params = {'product': products, 'range': range(n)}
return render(request,'home/home.html',params)
```

and the HTML for loop part is:

```
{% for i in range %}

    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 text-center mt-4 ">
         <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{product.i.product_name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

the problem is when I am typing `{{product.i.product_name}}` it is not giving the product name but it is working when I am giving value instead of I like `{{product.0.product_name}}`.
I am not understanding what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `product.i` then, you are looking up a property on `product` whose name is `i`. Here, `i` is a name, like any other property name and is not the variable `i`.

Fortunately there is a simple way to fix this issue. You can actually loop through the queryset `products` without using the indexes. All you need to do is:

```
{% for p in product %}
     <h5 class="card-title">{{p.product_name}}</h5>
{% endfor %}
```

(I have missed out the additional HTML just to make the answer clearer, but you can add that back in).

I would actually change the name of `product` in your `params` to `products`, then you can write the following:

```
{% for product in products %}
     <h5 class="card-title">{{product.product_name}}</h5>
{% endfor %}
```

(which is just a little easier to read).

I hope this helps :)

**EDIT: In answer to question in comments:**

The reason that this 'works' when you do `product.0` is that `0` is a value not a property name, so it is looking up the first (zeroith) element in the queryset. But because 0 doesn't change on each iteration of the loop, you are getting the same value every time, not a different one (as you have observed).

Comment: yes, it works but still not why it is happening because when I am printing the values of i it gives like 0,1,2,3 which i actually want but placing the same i in index place not working if you can explain elaborately it will be so helpful thank you :)

Comment: @TanmoyBhowmick hiya. Glad it helps. I've edited my answer to include an answer to your question above. If you're happy with the response please mark the answer as 'accepted'. Thanks